# How to make ride less bouncy?

Tags: suspension, opel, agila

In my 2003 Opel Agila, the ride is really bouncy. Whenever I go over bumps in the road, it feels like I am almost out of control.

It is generally a bouncy car, but it this one seems to be worse than the other Agila which I have driven.

How can I make it less "kangaroo like" over bumps at speed (40+ mph)?

EDIT: How can I test the shock absorbers before I replace them?

Comment: Only real thing I can tell you is to put better shocks on the car. Just a suggestion and I don't have a brand for you, either. If it bounces, it's a good indication the shocks could be bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if your suspension is kaput you will need to stand near each Axel and depress the fender, if it bounces up two or more times than they might be shot.

Alternatively you can manually inspect the suspension by checking each of the coils and dampers for any oil leaks (dampers) and deformities(Coils).

If all the above things are good then as paulster suggests , take it to a garage for a minor check.

Tip: what I usually do is take it to a wheel alignment shop and do smalltalk with the mechanics to know the condition of the suspension.. ( works most of the time and saves money ,also since they dont do  the service they will not recommend unnecessary part replacement also free advice)

Answer (score 3):

If the car feels like a galloping horse then chances are that the shock absorbers are non-functional.

An old-school method of testing the shocks is to press down on the front or back of the car and let go. If the car rebounds up and down 2-3 times it means the shocks are not doing their job.

Shocks can be replaced, but they can also be reconditioned by specialists.

Comment: I used to have the same car And I can tell you ... It was more unstable than a boat.. Above 80kmph Lol.